# Get all input type text elements AND drop-downs together

Tags: jquery

```
 $("#Lastform :input:text")
```

give all inputs of type text in Lastform

I want to get all input type text elements and drop-downs together

$("#Lastform :input:text AND all dropdowns")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this -

```
$("#Lastform input:text,#Lastform select")
```

You can join multiple selectors with `,`

Comment: THIS IS THE ANSWER :) TOGETHER IS THE KEY

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$("#Lastform").find('input:text, select')
```